Can an optical medium be lossless and dispersive?
Occasionally, I come across the phrase "lossless dispersive linear optical medium". How can such a medium be possible mathematically? I mean the real and imaginary parts of the electric susceptibility are related by the Kramers-Kronig relations. So it seems to me that if the imaginary part is zero at all frequencies, the real part must vanish or be a constant. Is "lossless dispersive linear optical medium" only some kind of approximation?

The K-K relation holds when considering the entire frequency range from dc to infinity. Across a narrower band one can have an essentially lossless and dispersive medium.

"Lossless dispersive linear medium" usually refers to some range of frequencies of interest, like (approximately) visible light in glass. Such medium may be lossy(absorptive) in some other range of frequencies (UV...). Thus susceptibility function $\tilde \chi(\omega)$of such medium can still obey the Kramers-Kronig (KK) relations.
If you're after a model of linear medium that is lossless for all frequencies $\omega>0$, and dispersive for some range of $\omega>0$, this certainly is mathematically possible. We can describe it using a susceptibility function in the frequency domain $\tilde{\chi}(\omega)$ that is real for all $\omega > 0$, but need not be real for $\omega<0$.
